# How to change ul list items from another onclick with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm starting to study jQuery.

I'm trying to show my second list of items in same place where the first list of items is, when i click in "show more links", but I'm not having success.

Can anyone give some help?

```
      <ul id="showfirst">
         <h1>Links</h1>
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="# id="next">show more links </a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="showsecond">
         <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">+ links</a></li>
      </ul>

   </section>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#next).click(function{

    $('#showsecond').show();

});
</script>
```

Comment: Quotes are out of balance.

Comment: And `function` must have parenthesis `()` before the opening curly bracket `{ `

Answer (score 4):

There is missing `()` and havn't closed string `'#next'`:

`$('#next).click(function{` should be `$('#next').click(function() {`

and unclosed quotes:

`<li><a href="#>` should be  `<li><a href="#"`

Comment: Also the selector is not "closed": it misses a `'`

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ added

Comment: there is 1 more mistake on the last anchor element of the 1st list. There is a missing `"` `(href="#)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#next').click(function() {

    $('#showsecond').show();

  });
});
```

```css
#showsecond {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="showfirst">
  <h1>Links</h1>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="next">show more links </a> </li>
</ul>

<ul id="showsecond">
  <li><a href="# ">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="# ">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="# ">Link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="# ">Link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="# ">+ links</a></li>
</ul>
```

You have to specify for the 2nd list to be hidden at first. Then you had a couple of mistakes (missing closing quote on 2 places, missing () after the `function` on your click event). And also you need to wrap your jquery code inside a `document.ready()` or in my code `$(function(){})` in order to prevent race conditions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you give explanations with your code ? He's learning javascript so he will need to know where it fails.

Answer (score 4):

```js
 $('#showsecond').hide();
 $("#next").click(function(){
 $("#next").closest('li').remove();
  var listItems = $("#showsecond li");
  listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    var product = $(li);
    $('#showfirst').append(product);
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="showfirst">
         <h1>Links</h1>
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="next">show more links </a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="showsecond">
         <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">+ links</a></li>
      </ul>

   </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check that you close your strings. There were some unterminated strings.

```js
 $('#next').click(function(){
    $('#showfirst').hide();
    $('#showsecond').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
     <h1>Links</h1>
     <ul id="showfirst">
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="next">show more links</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="showsecond" style="display:none;">
         <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">+ links</a></li>
      </ul>

</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Three issues:

- One `href="#` attribute is missing a closing double quote
- The function expression is missing parentheses. Should be `function () {`
- The selector `$('#next)` is missing a closing quote.

It helps to look at the console once in a while.

If you want the second list to be initially hidden then add an attribute to the HTML:

```
<ul id="showsecond" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#showsecond').hide();
$('#next').click(function(){
  $('#showsecond').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="showfirst">
  <h1>Links</h1>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="next">show more links </a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="showsecond">
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">+ links</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`var listItems = $("#showsecond li");` this statement will retrieve all the li tag elements then we trace these elements and append each those elements into the first list using `append()` function.
 `$('#showfirst').append(product);`

```js
 $('#showsecond').hide();
 $("#next").click(function(){
  var listItems = $("#showsecond li");
  listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    var product = $(li);
    $('#showfirst').append(product);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="showfirst">
         <h1>Links</h1>
         <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" id="next">show more links </a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="showsecond">
         <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">+ links</a></li>
      </ul>

   </section>
```

Comment: Is this is the output that you are expecting?